# Nokogiri for reading and editing Plist

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, plist

I need to read and edit part of a plist file, it looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Bookstore</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Public</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Books</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>The Old Man and the Sea</string>
                    <key>Author</key>
                    <string>Hemingway</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>A Brief History of Time</string>
                    <key>Author</key>
                    <string>Stephen Hawkin</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What I've done so far:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
doc = doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("books.plist"))
doc.xpath("//dict[key=\"Bookstore\"]/dict[key=\"Public\"]/dict[key=\"Books\"]")
```

If I want to get *an array of hashes (in Ruby)* of elements under "Book", what should I do next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can expand your selection to grab exactly the elements you need:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("books.plist"))
books = doc.xpath("//dict[key='Bookstore']/dict[key='Public']/dict[key='Books']/array/dict")
```

Then you can convert this array of book elements into the shape you want by sub-selecting, or traversing, but sub-selecting might look like this:

```
final = books.map do |book|
  keys = book.xpath("key/text()").map(&:to_s)
  values = book.xpath("string/text()").map(&:to_s)
  Hash[keys.zip(values)]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! If I change any of the value, say an aurhor of the book, how should I save it back to the original plist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby gems like [plist_lite](https://github.com/tonytonyjan/plist_lite)

To answer your question:

> If I want to get an array of hashes (in Ruby) of elements under "Book", what should I do next?

```sh
ruby -rplist_lite -e 'pp PlistLite.load($stdin.read)["Bookstore"]["Public"]["Books"]' <<EOS
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Bookstore</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Public</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Books</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>The Old Man and the Sea</string>
                    <key>Author</key>
                    <string>Hemingway</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>A Brief History of Time</string>
                    <key>Author</key>
                    <string>Stephen Hawkin</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
EOS
```

output

```
[{"Name"=>"The Old Man and the Sea", "Author"=>"Hemingway"},
 {"Name"=>"A Brief History of Time", "Author"=>"Stephen Hawkin"}]
```

If you don't want to require extra dependency, you can still refer to it's source code, `plist_lite` uses `nokogiri` for parsing as well:

https://github.com/tonytonyjan/plist_lite/blob/master/lib/plist_lite.rb#L37-L57

To update the plist file, use `PlistLite#dump`:

```rb
obj = PlistLite.load(IO.read('test.plist'))
# modify obj...
IO.write('test.plist', PlistLite.dump(obj))
```